# Routing Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have URLs like this :

"http://host.com/site/forum/1/General"
"http://host.com/site/forum/2/Special"
and more

I want to shorten the URLs like the given below:

"http://host.com/forum/General"
"http://host.com/forum/Special"
and more

In my route file, I have used the settings below which is not working, please have a look for the solution:

```
$route['forum/General'] = 'site/forum/1/General';
$route['forum/Special'] = 'site/forum/2/Special';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is best doable using [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)

Comment: it should work have you added .htaccess for removing your index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
```

But make sure that rewrite_module has been loaded on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your routes are overlapping ?
Post all your config/routes.php in order to see where the problem comes from !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? `$route['forum/General'] = 'site/forum/$1/General';`